# What would be the limits for further explanations to an answered question?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, scope

I had the following situation answering a question:

1. Answered correctly a basic question about a call to an undefined method with brief explanation, links to detailed info and a code sample.
2. The user commented the answer, with further problems on his code, not directly related to the original question.
3. As I was in good mood, I tried to help him, adding info that he could easily find in the links I provided, and some code as an **example** on how to solve the issues.
4. Apparently the guy copy-pasted my example to his code. Commented again saying that my code messed up his database.
5. I commented back saying that I was not going to take the blame, as what I posted was just an example, not a code to be pasted to his project.
6. He commented back, saying that he was not trying to put the blame on me. He just didn't understand what the code was doing.

What do you think would be the limits to further interaction after the original problem is solved? Should other issues in the same code be addressed in the same question or should we recommend the user to post new questions?

Comment: As @Makoto says.  Also, be on the lookout for an edit to the question that changes what it asks; it happens on a depressingly frequent basis that askers keep moving the goalposts, invalidating existing answers.  See [exit strategies for chamelon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) for how to deal with that.

Comment: Side note: "with further doubts on his code" - do you mean OP has concerns about they working code (US "doubts") like "they asked if their understanding of method X is correct" or you mean OP asked to fix another unrelated problem (non-US meaning of "doubts")? If it is separate problem replying with "please ask new clear question" would be right approach...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, that's where things start to blur: when you answer something, the OP asks something kind of related to the original question, than you answer and the OP asks another thing, distancing a bit more from the initial context at each interaction. I changed "doubts" to "problem" in my question to make it clearer

Comment: *"As I was in good mood, I tried to help him..."*. In my opinion, here is where you made a mistake. We have to nip this kind problem in the bud: whether in good mood or bad mood, in a situation like that I always reply *"this is an unrelated issue, please ask it as a new question"*.

Comment: Piling on to what others are saying: This happens to me quite often. I've learned to: 1) Explain site policy (one q / Q) with a link to [help]; 2) advise to therefore ask a new Q; 3) if there are some short/simple tips that could help get started, provide that (saying that's what this is); 4) NEVER add any of this to the Answer, only in a comment! 5) Then don't reply in that "thread" any further, but keep an eye on it for a day or so. I've had reasonably good experience with the approach: the serious thank and do as I recommend; the help-vampires pretty much disappear...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, the instant the user decided to blindly copy-paste your answer (which was intended as an example and not something that's production-ready), that's the point when your capability to actually *help* them came to an abrupt end.

You were doing the right thing in actually contributing to positive interactions with this person, but they didn't exercise the best faith on their part.

Best thing to do now is to just walk away.

Comment: ... after cleaning up the question if the OP edited answers in ...

Comment: if? you are so funny :)

Answer (score 1):

> The user commented the answer, with further problems on his code, not directly related to the original question.

Often the right approach here is to tell them to post a new question. If the asker is changing the question in a way that invalidates existing answers, do a rollback and inform them that SO is not intended for incremental debugging. Remember to do it in a kind way.